# LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates is never called

Tags: android, location, locationmanager

I have an application and I want to use the GPS's Location. After implementing what I was taught, I have two files, `VirtualAssistantActivity` which uses the `LocationGPS` file. The second file will send the result with an intent received from the first file.

The problem is the `TextView` that is supposed to be edited after receiving the intent filled with the `location.toString()` doesn't change. After using the debug feature of Android Studio, I've found that it's like the `locationManager`'s `requestLocationUpdate` is never called, I can't even get into the new `LocationListener`'s creation.

I am using a Sony XPERIA running Android 5.0, and decided to develop targeting Android 4.0 with API 15.

Here's the VirtualAssistantActivity code :

```
public class VirtualAssistantActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LocationGPS lgps = null;
private BroadcastReceiver mLocationReceiver;
private TextView tvTest = null;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_virtual_assistant);

    tvTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tV_testGeo);
    lgps = LocationGPS.get(this.getApplicationContext());
    mLocationReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
            Location l = (Location)intent.getParcelableExtra(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);
            if (l!=null){
                tvTest.setText(""+l);
            } else {
                tvTest.setText("Empty intent");
            }
        }
    };

}@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    this.registerReceiver(mLocationReceiver, new IntentFilter(LocationGPS.ACTION_LOCATION));
    lgps.startLocationUpdates();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BR Init", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //unregisterReceiver(mLocationReceiver);
}
```

And the LocationGPS's :

```
public class LocationGPS {

static LocationGPS slocationGPS = null;
Context mAppContext = null;
LocationManager mLocationManager = null;

public static String ACTION_LOCATION = "LOCATION_MSG";

private LocationGPS(Context appContext) {
    mAppContext = appContext;
    mLocationManager = (LocationManager)appContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
}

public static LocationGPS get(Context c) {
    if (slocationGPS == null) {
        slocationGPS = new LocationGPS(c);
    }
    return slocationGPS;
}

private void broadcastLocation(Location location) {
    Intent broadcast = new Intent(this.ACTION_LOCATION);
    broadcast.putExtra(LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED, location);
    this.mAppContext.sendBroadcast(broadcast);
}

public void startLocationUpdates(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mAppContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(mAppContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }

    mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates
            (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 5, new LocationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        //Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), location.toString());
                        Log.d("GPS", "Latitude " + location.getLatitude() + " et longitude " + location.getLongitude());
                        Toast.makeText(mAppContext, "Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        broadcastLocation(location);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(mAppContext, "Location", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            });
}
```

I've searched for some solutions, and while it seems to work for everyone, or at least they have some error messages, I don't know what I can do except eventually use Google's APIs, but I would prefer to avoid that. I have checked my permission, they're granted and this is a list of my imports:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager; 
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

And the permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: You don't need to grant both ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.  Just grant ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, and only do a check for that permission.  Also, can you post permissions on your manifest?

Comment: Ok I'll change that. Permissions edited ! I'm currently trying to use the LocationManager and Listener directly in the Activity. Maybe it'll work.